# retrieving the ID from a selected drop down list box in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have this:

```
<%= select("selected_red1_robot", "id", @robots.map { |u| [u.team_number,u.id]}) %>
```

when I do in my controller I see this:

```
params['selected_red1_robot']
```

and I see this in my return:

```
"selected_red1_robot"=>{"id"=>"2"}
```

I want to do something like:

```
@roboMatch.robot_id = params['selected_red1_robot']
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Generally you would have an association between 2 models.  I'm assuming one of your models is named 'robot'.  Is the other model named 'roboMatch'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to the id, you just need to reference it as follows:

`@roboMatch.robot_id = params['selected_red1_robot']['id']`